# Every rearrangement of an absolutely convergent series converges to the same sum (Rudin)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, absolute-convergence

[image]
[image]

What guarantees $\sum_{i=n}^m |a_i|$ will not be less than $|s_n-s_n'|$; hence $|s_n-s_n'| \ge \epsilon$?

May someone explain, please?

Comment: Can you tell us what the numbers $k_1,k_2,..,k_p$ are?  Also, I think you mean $|s_n-s_n'| \le \epsilon$ don't you?

Comment: @saulspatz I mean that if $\sum_{i=n}^m |a_i| \le |s_n-s_n'|$, then  $|s_n-s_n'| \ge \epsilon$

Comment: I see what you mean now, but you have the sense of the first inequality reversed.  Look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite follow the notation, but I see what he's saying.  Since the series converges, we know that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $N = N(\epsilon)$ such that $\sum_{N+1}^{\infty}{|a_n|} < \epsilon$.  Now $N$ is finite, so if we go out far enough in the rearrangement, say to M, we will encounter all the summands $a_1, a_2,..., a_n$ among the summands $a_1', a_2',...a_M'.$  Now look at $|s_M-s_M'|.$  All the terms up to $a-N$ have been cancelled out, by construction of M.  Some other terms are cancelled out also, but what matters is that any terms remaining are of the $|a_k|$ with $k>N$.  So, $|s_M-s_M'| <= \sum_{N+1}^{\infty}{|a_n|} < \epsilon.$